# Algorithm slower after having removed C++ template/typename

Tags: c++, templates, typename

For learning purposes and to understand how things work, I'm trying to rewrite this without templates, in the case `wstring`:

```
#include <ctype.h>

template<typename charT>
struct my_equal 
{
    bool operator()(charT ch1, charT ch2) { return toupper(ch1) == ch2; }
};

template<typename T>
bool contains(const T& str1, const T& str2)
{
    typename T::const_iterator it = std::search(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str2.begin(), str2.end(), my_equal<typename T::value_type>());
    return (it != str1.end());    
}
```

I'm trying this:

```
struct my_equal 
{
    bool operator()(wchar_t ch1, wchar_t ch2) { return toupper(ch1) == ch2; }
};

bool contains(const wstring str1, const wstring str2)
{
    wstring::const_iterator it = std::search(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str2.begin(), str2.end(), my_equal());
    return (it != str1.end());
}
```

**It works but it's twice or three times slower when benchmarking it. Why?**

Is there something wrong in the "translation without templates"?

Also, is it possible to avoid using a `struct` but having the `my_equal` comparison directly in `search(...)`?

Comment: Can you show how you benchmarked this?  They should in theory produce the exact same assembly.

Comment: @NathanOliver: will be difficult to show here, because it's part of a big application. Is `const T&` => `const wstring` correct? (what about the `&`?) Idem for `typename T::const_iterator` => `wstring::const_iterator`? `charT` => `wchar_t`?

Comment: Your non-template version likely makes a copy of the strings, whereas the template passes them as `const &`

Comment: @peterchen Good spot.  I missed that.  That will kill performance.

Comment: How to correct it @peterchen?

Comment: `const T& => const wstring&`

Comment: `bool contains(const wstring & str1, const wstring & str2)`   - see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: Ok that's the answer (if you want to copy/paste it as an answer!), thanks!

Comment: Last thing @NathanOliver and peterchen: can I avoid the `struct` and have a version with `search(..., my_eval_here_without_struct())` ?

Comment: @Basj You can use a function but you can get better performance with a functor.  With C++11/14 I would just use a lambda to make an anonymous functor.

Comment: @NathanOliver do you mean this: `[](wchar_t ch1, wchar_t ch2) { return toupper(ch1) == ch2; }`?

Comment: @Basj Yes.  That is a lambda.

Comment: I don't know whether to vote for closure as caused by a simple typographic error or a duplicate of the question explaining by-value vs by-reference.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver. I don't see much speed improvement, it even seems that it could be a little slower with this lambda instead of struct. Is there another way to make such a functor?

Comment: Nope.  You make a named class type or a lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omitted some ampersands.  Make it,

```
bool contains(const wstring &str1, const wstring &str2)
{
    wstring::const_iterator it = std::search(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str2.begin(), str2.end(), my_equal());
    return (it != str1.end());
}
```